# abusive registration?

Tags: domains

I once owned a gTLD domain that was none profit, there were a fair few links around the internet that linked to my site from other respected websites.  After my work was complete on this domain, I unfortunately let the domain fall to auction as I did not auto-renew.

Now this domain has pornography on it by the new owner and I am very worried as children may click on the links (containing my company name)found around the internet.

Please can someone advise me on the best route to sort this out? could this be considered an abusive registration?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sorry but questions like this are far to board and opinionated. Please ensure you read our [Help Center](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help) to avoid further disappointment. However your more than welcome to use our [chat channel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters) and in fact I've left you a message with my opinion.

Comment: Oh darn. I need a reputation of 20 to talk to you on the chat channel. We are a registered charity. It is reducing donations : /

Comment: Dang I want to answer this, but I am not sure what to say yet. I agree that the question is too broad, but I really really really feel for this guy(maybe assuming too much). Is there something we can do to help narrow the question and get some help for this guy??